# cakephp: strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Tags: php, cakephp

I working with cakephp. In all pages, there is this warning:

> Warning (2): strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given [CORE/src/Controller/Component/AuthComponent.php, line 337]

In line 337:

```
protected function _isAllowed(Controller $controller)
{
    $action = strtolower($controller->request->params['action']);
    return in_array($action, array_map('strtolower', $this->allowedActions));
}
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Show us what you get if you replace the `strtolower` line with `var_dump($controller->request->params['action']);exit;` Also tell us what you're trying to do.

Comment: probably `$this->allowedActions` contain a subarray. Please consider editing your question adding the debug of `$this->allowedActions`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood the reason for the warning and solved it. I used from

```
$this->Auth->allow(['display','add',['controller'=>'options','action'=>'add']]);
```

_isAllowd function checks whether current action is accessible without authentication. This warning is removed ‌by taking this line in AppController .

Answer (score 0):

Please check `$this->allowedActions` variable is one dimentional array or have sub array also using pr function.

```
pr($this->allowedActions);
die();
```

Note that multi dimentional array not work by passing inbuilt php function in with `array_map()`. You need to make custom function something like `custom_strtolower()`, and have to pass this function in `array_map()`.

I hope you will debug your self and my trick will be help full you.